# Append dictionary to a dictionary in powershell (hashtable)

Tags: powershell, dictionary

I have two dictionaries like this:

```
$first = @{}
$first.Add('John', 'Doe')
$first.Add('Johnny', 'Doe')


$second = @{}
$second.Add('Jack', 'Test')
$second.Add('Jacky', 'Test')
```

And I have a general `$all = @{}` dictionary, that stands for all dictionaries combined.

Ex. when I want to see all keys that `$all` contains:

```
foreach($key in $all){
    Write-Host $key
}
```

It will show this:

```
John
Johnny
Jack
Jacky
```

p.s. I have this one:

```
$all = @{}

$all_dict = @{}
$all_dict += $first
$all_dict += $second

foreach($dict in $all_dict){
    foreach($key in $dict.Key){
        $all.Add($key, $dict[$key])
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is another way to do it without the need to add all dictionaries to an array and then iterate through them

Comment: have you tried `$first.Keys + $second.Keys` yet?  [*grin*]

Comment: I think your ```$all_dict``` already contains what you want (i.e. a hashtable with all 4 entries), but your ```foreach( $dict in $all_dict )``` isn't enumerating the hashtable **entries** - it's enumerating the hashtable **object**, the same as ```foreach( $dict in @($all_dict) )```. Compare that to if you do ```foreach( $dict in $all_dict.GetEnumerator() )``` which will iterate over each entry in the hashtable.

Comment: watch out for it your keys collide as well - if you try ```@{ "aaa"="bbb"; "ccc"="ddd" } + @{ "aaa"="eee" }``` for example, you'll get an error ```Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'aaa'  Key being added: 'aaa'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do the `+=` addition to hashtables, but instead use a ForEach-Object on the hashes `.Keys`.  That way, the code can be shortened, but also it will leave you an easier choice whether you would want the possible duplicates from Hashtable 1 ($first) to be overwritten by the values from the second Hashtable ($second).

Something like this:

```
$first = @{}
$first.Add('John', 'Doe')
$first.Add('Johnny', 'Doe')

$second = @{}
$second.Add('Jack', 'Test')
$second.Add('Jacky', 'Test')
$second.Add('Johnny', 'Depp')  # Duplicate key: same first name, different lastname

$all = @{}
# copy all keys and values from the $first Hashtable into $all
$first.Keys | ForEach-Object { $all[$_] = $first[$_] }
```

For the next part, you'll have to decide what to do with duplicate keys:

Method 1

```
# add the stuff from Hashtable $second to it:
# this will overwrite the value if the key already exists (i.e. $second value 'wins')
$second.Keys | ForEach-Object { $all[$_] = $second[$_] }
```

OR use Method 2

```
# make sure the value of the $first hashtable is NOT overwritten (i.e. $first value 'wins')
$second.Keys | ForEach-Object { if (!($all.ContainsKey($_))) { $all[$_] = $second[$_] }}
```

In case you choose to overwrite (method 1), the $all hash will contain

> ```
> Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                  
> ----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                  
> John                           Doe                                                                                                                                                                    
> Jacky                          Test                                                                                                                                                                   
> Johnny                         Depp                                                                                                                                                                   
> Jack                           Test
> ```

If you choose NOT to overwrite (method 2), $all will be

> ```
> Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                  
> ----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                  
> John                           Doe                                                                                                                                                                    
> Jacky                          Test                                                                                                                                                                   
> Johnny                         Doe                                                                                                                                                                    
> Jack                           Test
> ```

---

**Edit**

There is another approach where you rely on the fact that an exception is thrown if you try to add an entry that already exists. In that case, use the `.Add(key, value)` method and wrap it inside a `try{..} catch{..}` block.
Without that catch, the error prevents the `$all` Hashtable to be filled, as it stops at the first duplicate key you try to add.

```
$second.Keys | ForEach-Object { 
    try {
        $all.Add($_, $second[$_])
    }
    catch {
        # catch the exception in order to carry on adding items
        # the effect will be that the values from $first will not be overwritten
        # just like with method 2
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it throw an error when trying to add duplicate keys? Because that's what I need here

Comment: @ErtanHasani No, with methods 1 and 2 there won't be any exceptions thrown. I have added a third approach where we use the Hashtable's `.Add()` method inside a `try{..} catch{..}` block to handle the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `$all_dict` already contains what you want (i.e. a hashtable with all 4 entries), but your `foreach( $dict in $all_dict )` isn't enumerating the hashtable entries like you expect it to.

The quick answer is to iterate over the `Keys` collection instead:

```bsh
foreach( $key in $all.Keys )
{
   write-host $key
}
```

The longer answer is that in your example PowerShell is doing some "helper" things for you with enumeration - `foreach($key in $all)` is only enumerating over a single object (`$all`), but `write-host $all` is evaluating an array of all of the entries in `$all` and serializing them into a single string:

Compare the behaviour of these two lines and you can see the difference:

```bsh
PS> foreach($item in @{ "aaa"="bbb"; "ccc"="ddd" }) { write-host $item }
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

PS> foreach($item in @{ "aaa"="bbb"; "ccc"="ddd" }.Keys) { write-host $item }
ccc
aaa
```

By the way, watch out for if your keys collide - if you try `@{ "aaa"="bbb"; "ccc"="ddd" } + @{ "aaa"="eee" }` for example, you'll get an error `Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'aaa' Key being added: 'aaa'.` so you might want to find a better way to merge your hashtables rather than just using `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Am I not understanding the question?  You can add them.

```
$first = @{John = 'Doe'; Johnny = 'Doe'} # hashtables
$second = @{Jacky = 'Test'; Jack = 'Test'}
$all = $first + $second  # merge two hashtables
foreach ($i in $all.getenumerator()) { $i } # loops 4 times
```